# deque iterator out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to shuffle through some array-like object. I want to add a value to the front, and then pop off the last value. I tried using deque as per suggestions I have seen to other posts but I am still getting errors. Any ideas? I am new to C++ and while I could try to write around this issue I would like to know where it is so I can fix it.

I am getting a: cannot seek deque iterator out of range debug error from visual studio.

The function that was causing problems:

(I was originally using vectors)

```
void vector_pusher(deque <int> &v, int new_val ) { 
v.push_front(new_val);
v.erase(v.begin() + 3);
}
```

Here is the rest of my code (maybe it's a constuctor issue?):

```
#include "lock.h"
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

lock::lock(int x, int y, int z) {
    is_closed = true;
    current_top = 0;
    comb[0] = x % MAX_VAL;
    comb[1] = y % MAX_VAL;
    comb[2] = z % MAX_VAL;
    deque <int> trycomb = { 1, 1, 1 };
    deque <char> trydir = { 'q', 'q', 'q' };
    deque <int> rot = { 1,1,1 };
}

void lock::turn(int input, char direction, int rotation) {

    vector_pusher(trydir, direction);
    vector_pusher(trycomb, input);
    vector_pusher(rot, rotation);

}
```

In lock.h:

```
 public:
        lock(int, int, int);
        void turn(int, char, int);
        \* these functions are defined elsewhere and doing fine
        void new_comb(int, int, int);
        void open_close();
        bool lock_status() const;
        *\

        //entered combination
        deque <int> trycomb;

        // entered diections
        deque <char> trydir;

        //entered rotations (0 is directly too, 1 is around once)
        deque <int> rot;



    private:
        // current correct combo
        deque <int> comb = {0, 0, 0};

        //top val
        //this is unessesary
        int current_top;

        //open-ness state of lock
        bool is_closed;

        //needed directions
        deque <char> dir = {'r', 'l', 'r'};
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're never initializing `trycomb`, `trydir`, and `rot` in your constructor. You're declaring local variables in the constructor with the same name, which are shadowing the member variables of your `lock` class. Your constructor should look like this:

```
lock::lock(int x, int y, int z) {
    is_closed = true;
    current_top = 0;
    comb[0] = x % MAX_VAL;
    comb[1] = y % MAX_VAL;
    comb[2] = z % MAX_VAL;
    trycomb = { 1, 1, 1 };
    trydir = { 'q', 'q', 'q' };
    rot = { 1,1,1 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you must change your constructor to

```
lock::lock(int x, int y, int z) {
    is_closed = true;
    current_top = 0;
    comb[0] = x % MAX_VAL;
    comb[1] = y % MAX_VAL;
    comb[2] = z % MAX_VAL;
    trycomb = { 1, 1, 1 };
    trydir = { 'q', 'q', 'q' };
    rot = { 1,1,1 };
}
```

otherwise the class members will not be initialized.

Secondly, you should use `pop_front` if you want to remove the first element in the queue and `pop_back` to remove the last element in the queue (see the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) of deque). This makes the code much more readable.